# Language-agnostic Robotium tests

Tags: android, testing, robotium

Is possible to write language agnostic Robotium tests? For example, if you use a PreferenceActivity, by definition there is no way to get an R.id reference to it.

Is there a mechanism to support this? Or maybe a way for Robotium to read from the String file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read from the application-under-test's strings.xml file from a Robotium test by simply  accessing the current activity:

```
String myString = getActivity().getString(R.string.my_string);
```

Comment: Ah, sorry, after trying this, it turns it doesn't work. I can't get to the R.string of the project I'm testing on, only the strings of the test project.

Comment: This does work I use it in almost every test I write, there must be something wrong with the setup of your test project.